# How to use 'find' to return parent directory

Tags: bash

I am using find to locate a file, but I want to only return the path to the parent directory of the file.

```
find /home/ -name 'myfile' -type f
```

That returns a list of the full path to all of the file matches, but I want to

Comment: sorry, just to clear it up a little: do you mean the parent directory of (the directory containing the file) or the actual directory that contains the file in question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

one way of many:

```
find /   -name 'myfile' -type f -exec dirname {} \;
```

Answer (score 11):

The -printf action lets you extract lots of information about the file.  '%h' is the directive to get the path part of the file name.

`find /home/ -name 'myfile' -type f -printf '%h\n'`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute something in the directory of the found file you may want to use `-execdir` action.

```
find /home/ -name 'myfile' -type f -print -execdir chmod -c 700 . \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /home/ -name 'myfile' -type f|awk -f"/" '{print $(NF-1), "/",$NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/ -name 'myfile' -type f | rev | cut -d "/" -f2- | rev | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home; find . -name 'myfile' -type f | sed "s/\/[^/]*$//" | cut -d "/" -f2- | sort -u
```